# How do I get the cursor back in Visual Studio 2010 RC Windows Forms designer after drawing controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2010

I am not sure if this is a bug or if I'm just missing something, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get my cursor back in the Windows Forms designer in [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010).

I opened up an existing project and added a group box, now my cursor is stuck drawing group boxes.  I just want the simple pointer cursor back, but nothing I do seems to bring it back.

I almost expected it to be on the toolbox under "Cursor", but it's not.

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting a vote to close as this is a valid question about an IDE.

Comment: So we're voting to close questions based on popularity now?  I can understand down votes or just the fact that no one answers, thats fine, but voting to close seems lame.

Comment: @Hans "Such an answer is going to be completely irrelevant in a few months". Indeed. Here I am, nearly 2 years down the road, very happy to find the solution to this annoying problem. Good question, answer that solves the problem, and AFAIK is only to be found here. Just look at the number of up-votes >;-)

Comment: @smirkingman I agree with *smirkingman*. I ran into this problem today and was able to use an answer to fix it immediately.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This problem appears because VS 2010 imports the settings from previous versions.
In order to fix it right click over the toolbox and select Reset Toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug. Close Visual Studio 2010 and reopen. In the toolbox, the "Pointer" should be at the top of every tab. Also the pointer should work like it did in Visual Studio 2008; it will revert back to the pointer after drawing one control.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Guthrie announced today that the Visual Studio team now has a [Patch for VS 2010 RC Intellisense Crash Issue](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/15/patch-for-vs-2010-rc-intellisense-crash-issue-now-available.aspx). It seems that a late fix right before they shipped the RC modified a UI input code path that unfortunately exposed a pretty dramatic bug. You should be able to get the patch from the [Microsoft Connect Website](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=26662).

Hope this helps some.